# How can I convert a CSV string to a TMap in Unreal Engine 4 using FMapProperty/UMapProperty?

Tags: c++, parsing, data-structures, properties, unreal-engine4

I've been working on an alternative to UE4's data table system but when converting a CSV string containing a array or map, the string conversion can get messed up if it contains comma's anywhere else except between the elements. So I looked at how UE4's data tables handle it and found that it uses the ImportText function on f and u properties. The problem is I can't get it to populate the TMap property I use it on.

Photo of what strings I've tried passing into it and how I formatted them.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KApoM.png)

Test 1
In the first test I tried to apply the same method I used for the string test which resulted in the fall back else statement being triggered

```
//Test struct
USTRUCT(Blueprintable)
struct FMyStruct
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    UPROPERTY()
    FString StrValue;

    UPROPERTY()
    TMap<FString, FString> MapValue;
};

void UMyTestFunctionLibrary::MyTMapTest(FString TMapString)
{
    FMyStruct MyStruct;
        
        //Loop through properties
    for (TFieldIterator<FProperty> It(MyStruct.StaticStruct()); It; ++It)
    {
                //String value assignment set test
        if (It->GetName() == "StrValue")
        {
            FStrProperty* Str = Cast<FStrProperty>(*It);
            if (Str)
            {
                Str->ImportText(TEXT("BB"), Str->ContainerPtrToValuePtr<void*>(&MyStruct), EPropertyPortFlags::PPF_None, nullptr);
            }
        }
                //Map value assignment set test
        else if (It->GetName() == "MapValue")
        {
            FMapProperty* Str = Cast<FMapProperty>(*It);
            if (Str)
            {
                Str->ImportText(*TMapString, Str->ContainerPtrToValuePtr<void*>(&MyStruct), EPropertyPortFlags::PPF_Delimited, nullptr);
            }
        }
    }


        //Test string contents
    if (GEngine)
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, MyStruct.StrValue);


        //Test map contents
    if (MyStruct.MapValue.Contains("Key"))
    {
        if (GEngine)
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, MyStruct.MapValue["Key"]);
    }
        //Else fall back
    else
    {
        TArray<FString> Arr;
        MyStruct.MapValue.GetKeys(Arr);
        for (FString& K: Arr)
        {
            if (GEngine)
                GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, K);
        }
        if (GEngine)
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Fin"));
    }
    
}
```

Test 2
In the second example I tried copying how its done in FDataTableImporterCSV ReadTable() function, which also resulted in the fall back being triggered when attempting to access

```
//Test struct
USTRUCT(Blueprintable)
struct FMyStruct
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    UPROPERTY()
    FString StrValue;

    UPROPERTY()
    TMap<FString, FString> MapValue;
};



void UMyTestFunctionLibrary::MyTMapTest(FString TMapString) {

    FMyStruct MyStruct;

        //Loop through properties
    for (TFieldIterator<FProperty> It(MyStruct.StaticStruct()); It; ++It)
    {
                //Assign string property test
        if (It->GetName() == "StrValue")
        {
            FStrProperty* Str = Cast<FStrProperty>(*It);
            if (Str)
            {
                Str->ImportText(TEXT("BB"), Str->ContainerPtrToValuePtr<void*>(&MyStruct), EPropertyPortFlags::PPF_None, nullptr);
            }
        }
                //Assign map property test
        else if (It->GetName() == "MapValue")
        {
            UScriptStruct* Var = MyStruct.StaticStruct();
            uint8* RowData = (uint8*)FMemory::Malloc(Var->GetStructureSize());
            Var->InitializeStruct(RowData);

            DataTableUtils::AssignStringToProperty(TMapString, *It, RowData);

            
        }
    }

        
        //Test string contents
    if (GEngine)
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, MyStruct.StrValue);



        //Test map contents
    if (MyStruct.MapValue.Contains("Key"))
    {
        if (GEngine)
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, MyStruct.MapValue["Key"]);
    }
        //Fall back test
    else
    {
        TArray<FString> Arr;
        MyStruct.MapValue.GetKeys(Arr);
        for (FString& K: Arr)
        {
            if (GEngine)
                GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, K);
        }
        if (GEngine)
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Fin"));
    }
    
}
```